# How to create msi from exe for GPO with WIX toolset

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, exe

I would like to deploy software via GPO and therefore I need .msi-Files, to install the programs silently.
I need help to create .msi-Files from various .exe-Files (e.g. Firefox, Adobe, notepad++, etc.). After some research I found a tool [wix toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/), but I have absolutely no idea how to generate msi from exe!

Can someone explain how to simple convert exe to msi with "WIX Toolset" or give me advice for another solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone explain how to simple convert exe to msi with "WIX
>   Toolset" or give me advice for another solution?

WiX toolset is **not** made for that. It is intended for creating installers from scratch.

Many installers (mostly these from the big companies) that come as a single EXE file are actually MSI packages bundled together. So you could first look for ways to unpack the EXE file into the separate MSI packages. There are many techniques to create such a EXE, so I can't tell you how to unpack these in general. Sometimes there is a special command-line parameter for this, sometimes you have to run the installer and grab the MSI files from temp directory.

Running such extracted MSI files is not always possible without further ado because they can depend on parameters passed from the EXE file. If not documented, you could try to figure out these parameters from [installation log files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/223300/how-to-enable-windows-installer-logging).

Another technique is to use a MSI *repackaging tool*. Such a tool usually creates a snapshot of the system before installation, runs the installer and creates a second snapshot. From the difference between both snapshots it determines the changes made to the system and creates an MSI package from that. This technique is not perfect because it may record too much if unrelated changes happen to the system in between (e. g. Windows updates). It may also record too little if the system already has some prerequisites installed, which the installer includes.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. I gave "Exe to MSI Converter Pro" a try and it seems to do the job. As you said it just repackage the exe.